# Appium Server does not start due to main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-intent, appium

Appium used to start just fine all of a sudden I get the following console log.  **Bear in mind I am starting appium through the console and not the command line.**

```
[--localizable-strings-dir LOCALIZABLESTRINGSDIR] [--app APP]
            [--ipa IPA] [-U UDID] [-a ADDRESS] [-p PORT]
            [-ca CALLBACKADDRESS] [-cp CALLBACKPORT] [-bp BOOTSTRAPPORT]
            [-k] [-r BACKENDRETRIES] [--session-override] [--full-reset]
 main.js: error: argument "--app": Expected one argument. null
            [--no-reset] [-l] [-lt LAUNCHTIMEOUT] [-g LOG]
            [--log-level {info,info:debug,info:info,info:warn,info:error,warn,warn:debug,warn:info,warn:warn,warn:error,error,error:debug,error:info,error:warn,error:error,debug,debug:debug,debug:info,debug:warn,debug:error}]    
            [--log-timestamp] [--local-timezone] [--log-no-colors]
            [-G WEBHOOK] [--native-instruments-lib]
            [--app-pkg ANDROIDPACKAGE] [--app-activity ANDROIDACTIVITY]
            [--app-wait-package ANDROIDWAITPACKAGE]
            [--app-wait-activity ANDROIDWAITACTIVITY]
            [--android-coverage ANDROIDCOVERAGE] [--avd AVD]
            [--avd-args AVDARGS]
            [--device-ready-timeout ANDROIDDEVICEREADYTIMEOUT] [--safari]
            [--device-name DEVICENAME] [--platform-name PLATFORMNAME]
            [--platform-version PLATFORMVERSION]
            [--automation-name AUTOMATIONNAME] [--browser-name BROWSERNAME]
            [--default-device] [--force-iphone] [--force-ipad]
            [--language LANGUAGE] [--locale LOCALE]
            [--calendar-format CALENDARFORMAT] [--orientation ORIENTATION]
            [--tracetemplate AUTOMATIONTRACETEMPLATEPATH] [--show-sim-log]
            [--show-ios-log] [--nodeconfig NODECONFIG] [-ra ROBOTADDRESS]
            [-rp ROBOTPORT] [--selendroid-port SELENDROIDPORT]
            [--chromedriver-port CHROMEDRIVERPORT]
            [--chromedriver-executable CHROMEDRIVEREXECUTABLE]
            [--use-keystore] [--keystore-path KEYSTOREPATH]
            [--keystore-password KEYSTOREPASSWORD] [--key-alias KEYALIAS]
            [--key-password KEYPASSWORD] [--show-config] [--no-perms-check]
            [--command-timeout DEFAULTCOMMANDTIMEOUT] [--keep-keychains]
            [--strict-caps] [--isolate-sim-device] [--tmp TMPDIR]
            [--trace-dir TRACEDIR] [--intent-action INTENTACTION]
            [--intent-category INTENTCATEGORY] [--intent-flags INTENTFLAGS]
            [--intent-args OPTIONALINTENTARGUMENTS]
```

Node Server Process Ended

Answer (score 0):

Even I have an issue like

main.js: error: argument "--avd-args": Expected one argument. null

Trying to Pre launch an additional emulator from the appium. But it requires Arguments..

Answer (score 0):

What I did to solve the problem was go into the settings of appium and toggle with the checkable boxes.  then, I pressed start server button and it started working.  Before that, nothing worked.  So, it may have just been a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Unchecked all the settings in android portion and  rerun the program it will run .

this  should be  displayed on  ur  system

Starting Node Server

> info: Welcome to Appium v1.3.7 (REV 72fbfaa116d3d9f6a862600ee99cf02f6d0e2182)
>   info: Appium REST http interface listener started on 127.0.0.1:4723
>   info: [debug] Non-default server args: {"address":"127.0.0.1","logNoColors":true,"platformName":"Android","platformVersion":"19","automationName":"Appium"}
>   info: Console LogLevel: debug

Answer (score 0):

Solution is to either provide a valid apk path in the Android settings -->Application path or uncheck the Application path checkbox.